# Cannot set properties of default fields on SP.Folder item with JS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom, jsom

I'm working on code to create and set properties of folders in SP 2013 with JSOM. My current setup involves the following:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle)
var folder = list.get_rootFolder().add("TestFolder");
ctx.load(folder);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
   var properties = folder.get_properties();
   //Default field of "Title" is not set
   properties.set_item('Title' : "test title");
   //Custom field that I created is successfully set
   properties.set_item('CustomField' : 'test value');
   folder.update();
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
      console.log("Done");
   });
});
```

I tried this with other prexisting fields as well and they didn't exist, but my custom fields can all be set fine. What do I need to do? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out!

I printed out all the fields and noticed default fields were prefixed with "vti_", so if I do properties.set_item('vti_title': 'test title') this works fine.

It seems that any default field can be prefixed with vti at least in my environment. If anyone has an explanation please let me know!